# How to put a levelspec in operator form?

Tags: core-language, map, operators

All variable argument functions need `Function` wrapped around them in operator form, but is there any other way to achieve this:

```
Map[f, {-1}]@{{a, b}, c, d, e}
```

than

```
Function[l, Map[f, l, {-1}]]@{{a, b}, c, d, e}
```

since Map isn't varargs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) to represent the argument and include `&` in short form

```
Function[l, Map[f, l, {-1}]]@{{a, b}, c, d, e}

(* {{f[a], f[b]}, f[c], f[d], f[e]} *)

Map[f, #, {-1}] &[{{a, b}, c, d, e}]

(* {{f[a], f[b]}, f[c], f[d], f[e]} *)

Map[f, #, {-1}] &@{{a, b}, c, d, e}

(* {{f[a], f[b]}, f[c], f[d], f[e]} *)

% == %% == %%%

(*  True *)
```

Comment: @M.R. I mean, seriously. If you evaluate `Map[f, {-1}][{a, b,c}]` you will likely see why the "obvious" syntax you propose would not have any chance of working. (Because it already "works" just fine, and does something very different.)

Comment: Omg did I really make such a silly mistake?

Comment: It was late and I didn't have my glasses, I thought the brackets where parentheses. Somebody please delete this question, too embarrassing ;)